# How to remove required attribute after select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did an asset delivery system so there are two options for the user to select which is NOT YET DELIVERED and ALREADY DELIVERED.

I used javascript to allow date input to display if the user selects ALREADY DELIVERED. I added `required` for the calendar so that the user cannot submit the details if user doesn't choose a date and it worked perfectly.

However,when the user selects NOT YET DELIVERED, the system doesn't display the calendar and therefore cannot submit the form due to the calendar being `required`.

I wanted the calendar to be `required` if the user selects ALREADY DELIVERED but not for NOT YET DELIVERED.

Thank you in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  with name = 'status') $(document).on("change", "input[name='status']", function() {
  console.log("Testing");
  var checkedValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(checkedValue);

  else;
  checkedValue == 1 ? $(".box").show() : $(".box").hide();
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="alignright">
  <div>
    <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" required /> Not yet 
                                                                     delivered
      </label>
    <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" required /> Already 
                                                                     delivered
      </label>
  </div>
</span>
<span class="alignleft">
  <div class="box">DELIVERY DATE<input type="date" name="deliverydate" 
         id="deliverydate" required="" />
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the required value on the date input, set it depending on which option the user selects. You can do this at the same time as hiding/showing it.

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[name='status']", function() {
  var checkedValue = $(this).val();
  
  if(checkedValue == 1){
    $(".box").show();
    $(".box").prop("required",true);
  } else {
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".box").prop("required",false);
  }
  
  console.log($(".box").prop("required"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="alignright">
  <div>
    <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" required /> Not yet 
                                                                     delivered
      </label>
    <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" required /> Already 
                                                                     delivered
      </label>
  </div>
</span>
<span class="alignleft">
  <div class="box">DELIVERY DATE<input type="date" name="deliverydate" 
         id="deliverydate" />
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$(function() { 
  with name='status')
  $(document).on("change", "input[name='status']", function() {
    console.log("Testing");
    var checkedValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(checkedValue);

    else;

    if(checkedValue == 1) {
       $(".box").show();
       $('input#deliverydate').prop('required',true);
    } else {
       $(".box").hide();
       $('input#deliverydate').prop('required',false);
    }
  })
});
```

Hope it helps.